# How to get all open resources a ruby process opens

Tags: ruby

I know every unix process comes with three open resources, `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR`,
and if I open a file like:

```
passwd = File.open('/etc/passwd')
puts passwd.fileno`
```

the number of these resources will increase. Is there any way to get all resources that a ruby process opens?

Answer (score 2):

Even running an external process within Ruby does not usually open different `IO` objects. The same `STDERR`, `STDOUT`, and `STDIN` will be shared unless you explicitly change them. To get all the `IO`s, you can do this:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(IO).to_a
# => [
#   #<IO:<STDERR>>,
#   #<IO:<STDOUT>>,
#   #<IO:<STDIN>>,
#   #<IO:fd 1>,
#   #<IO:fd 0>,
#   #<File:/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/lc/error.rb (closed)>
# ]
```